# MySQl replace with auto increment primary and MUL secondary keys

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have an existing table that I was populating overnight via a script that reads and converts a binary format file into a sequence of `replace` statements that are piped into `mysql`.  The script had a bug and looped over each binary file twice, so every `replace` statement was issued two times.

Now the table has auto incremented primary key, and the replace statements do not specify it.  I was expecting to get two entries (with different integer primary key value).  I actually don't get the repetitions.

More detail:

From `describe a.b`:

```
 Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra
 ------|---------|------|-----|---------|---------------
 id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
 name  | char(8) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
 date  | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |
 size  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

A sample `replace` statement is

```
replace into a.b (name,date,size) values ('Joe',20180105,32100);
```

After the script runs I look at the entries in the table, and there is only one entry for `Joe` on the given date with the given size.  Result from `select * from a.b where name='Joe' and date=20180105` is:

```
id     | name | date       | size
-------|------|------------|------
20423  | Joe  | 2018-01-05 | 32100
```

(Whereas I expected to see another line with a different `id` and the same values in the remaining columns.)

I seem to have the answer that I want here in that, had the script run properly, each `replace` statement would have only appeared once anyway, but I don't understand why (and therefore don't completely trust it).

**EDIT**

In response to comments, here is the result from `show index from a.b` (I rounded the cardinality numbers when I brought it over):

```
Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment
------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+--------
b     | 0          | PRIMARY  | 1            | id          | A         | 1000000     | Null     | Null   | YES  | BTREE      |
b     | 0          | n_d      | 1            | name        | A         | 100         | Null     | Null   | YES  | BTREE      |
b     | 0          | n_d      | 2            | date        | A         | 10000       | Null     | Null   | YES  | BTREE      |
```

So, I think maybe I misunderstood the meaning of `MUL` in the result from describe?  From the documentation:

> If Key is MUL, the column is the first column of a nonunique index in which multiple occurrences of a given value are permitted within the column.

It was the "nonunique"  there that made me think this wasn't causing lines to get killed on the second replace.  Was it instead just marking that `name` by itself is not uniquely indexed (even though, in total, the `n_d` index is unique)?

Comment: Regarding your last question, If there is a unique index on name and date, since you are replacing those two columns in your replace statement, the behavior as mentioned in my answer is what would be expected, and is what you say happened in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to reproduce your observation (in mariadb anyway).

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t
    -> (id    int auto_increment primary key,
    -> name   char(8) null default null,
    -> date   date  null  default null,
    -> size   int  null default null
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> alter table t
    -> add key tk1(name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> describe t;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | char(8) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date  | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| size  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> replace t (name,date,size) values ('aaa','2018-01-30',1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> replace t (name,date,size) values ('aaa','2018-01-31',2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------+------------+------+
| id | name | date       | size |
+----+------+------------+------+
|  1 | aaa  | 2018-01-30 |    1 |
|  2 | aaa  | 2018-01-31 |    2 |
+----+------+------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You changed the date between the two `replace` statements, so that's different than the issue that I raised.  I agree with what you get when the `values` are different.

Comment: True but just reran it with exactly the same data and and got same result.

Comment: That's what I would have expected, so....  Not sure what's happening with mine.  I appreciate your test.

Answer (score 0):

With replace, if a duplicate row is found (same primary key and/or unique key), the existing row is deleted and a new row is inserted. So you shouldn't see another row with the same values. If you have any unique keys on the other columns (other than the primary key), then you would see the results you found. Since you didn't show the keys for the table, this is just a guess.

From the SQL Manual:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT , except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Comment: The primary key is the `id`, which is auto incremented, as shown in the question.

Comment: Obviously. I was referring to any other columns which might have a unique key.

Comment: Not obviously to me, but I think you're onto the answer. I may have misunderstood the `MUL` showing under the `Key` column in the `describe` result. I'm editing my question now.

Comment: By "Obviously", I was referring to your point that ```id``` is the primary key as stated in your question. In your edit, you use the term "mul". Did you mean "null"? Also, it appears that you have unique indexes on columns in addition to the ```id``` column. That would explain the results you are seeing.

Comment: `MUL` is taken directly from the documentation and also appears in the `describe` result under the `Key` column.